# How to omit the user prompt when storing result of eval in a Bash variable?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, passwords, keepass

I would like to retrieve a password from a Keepass database using `keepassxc-cli` within a (backup) shell script. (For security purposes it would rather not save it within a text file on my file system.) The required command looks like this:

`/Applications/KeePassXC.app/Contents/MacOS/keepassxc-cli show -a Password --key-file=/path/to/keyfile /path/to/database.kdbx "/path/to/entry/within/database"`

When entering this command manually on my terminal, I get prompted for my master password and then, after entering this master password, the referenced password is shown on the next line:

```
Enter password to unlock /path/to/database.kdbx: <me_entering_my_master_password>
TESTPASSWORD
```

The relevant part of my script looks like this (whereby the aforementioned command is stored as a string in `KEEPASSCMD` and I'm just echoing for debugging purposes):

```
REPOPASSWORD=$(eval $KEEPASSCMD)
echo $REPOPASSWORD
```

When running the script, however, I don't get prompted to enter my master password but instead nothing is shown on the terminal. After "blindly" entering my master password, the following output is shown:

```
Enter password to unlock /path/to/database.kdbx: TESTPASSWORD
```

That is, the prompt is stored within `REPOPASSWORD`, too. Is it somehow possible to exclude the prompt, so only the string `TESTPASSWORD` gets stored in `REPOPASSWORD`?

Answer (score 0):

Which shell are you using? Your code works for me both on bash and zsh with keepassxc 2.6.2. Have you tried without eval?

```
REPOPASSWORD=$(/Applications/KeePassXC.app/Contents/MacOS/keepassxc-cli show -a Password --key-file=/path/to/keyfile /path/to/database.kdbx "/path/to/entry/within/database")
echo $REPOPASSWORD
```